# tail -f nohup.out gives cannot open 'nohup.out' for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, nohup

I connected to a remote server using ssh protocol and launched this command in order to run my python script remotely:

```
nohup python3.8 -u sab.py > log_15_09_2023.txt &
```

This works fine since if I type `top` I can see my script being currently ran.

However if I type

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

I get:

> tail: cannot open 'nohup.out' for reading: No such file or directory
> tail: no files remaining

So I tried `tail -f ./nohup.out` but I get the same error.

If I type `pwd` I get `/home/alex` and if I print `ls -i -l` I get :

```
total 92
3414135 -rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex 25538 Sep 15 16:41 log_15_09_2023.txt
3409134 -rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex   522 Sep 13 17:15 requirements.txt
3414133 -rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex  9585 Sep 15 13:18 sab.py
3407895 drwxrwxr-x 7 alex alex  4096 Sep 13 17:04 venv
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man 1 nohup`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/nohup.1.en#DESCRIPTION) [emphasis mine]:

> […] **If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if possible, `$HOME/nohup.out` otherwise.** If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE`.

This means the default filename `nohup.out` is used when standard output is a terminal. In your case it's not a terminal, it's a regular file named `log_15_09_2023.txt`.

By redirecting to `log_15_09_2023.txt` you made `nohup` use this exact file *instead of `nohup.out`*. You did not redirect standard error, it was a terminal, so `nohup` automatically redirected it to standard output, i.e. also to this file.

Instead of `tail -f nohup.out` you should invoke:

```
tail -f log_15_09_2023.txt
```

It will work, the file is there.